# How do I export variable labels in R?

Tags: r, label, export-to-csv

When I export a data.frame as a csv, I'd like to include the descriptions of the variables—labels I either created or inherited from SPSS. These labels are an easy way to keep track of what each variable encodes, and they display in Rstudio View(). Consider the following:

```
attach(iris)
setattr(iris$Sepal.Length, "label", "The length of a sepal in cm")
setattr(iris$Species, "label", "Species of iris")
```

Neither write.csv() or fwrite() seems to have a built-in option preserve these labels. Can you suggest a workaround or another function that will do so?

Comment: Consider saving it as dta file using write.dta() from foreign package.

Comment: Function `write_labelled_csv` in package `expss` will write the labels as commented text at the top of the file.